# Делегирование событий javascript - один обработчик на несколько инпутов

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 10 блоков див с инпутами

И функция javascript   одна и та же на все дивы с инпутами..., котрая ограничивает ввод символов до 15.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let name = document.querySelector('#text1');
  text1.oninput = function(){
  this.value = this.value.substr(0,15);
  }
</script>
```

Пытался делегировать, перебирать и тд., но не получается, даже код стыдно показывать.
Есть ли простое и понятное решение, чтобы был один обработчик на несколько инпутов?

Продолжение вопроса: [Один обработчик на несколько инпутов, в нескольких дивах с двумя инпутами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489839)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы лично предпочёл [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation):

```js
window.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target

  if(input.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, 15)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
<div class="text">  <input type="text" /> </div>
```

Comment: Это было бы лучшим решением, но у меня не все импуты должны быть ограничены при вводе...есть рядом текстовые импуты где нужно больше символов вводить.. Их как то можно в вашем коде отделить..? Т.е. в каждом диве два инпута, 1) для ссылки, 2) название ссылки (кнопки).... ограничиваю только название

Comment: @JandosM можно проверять `input` на совпадение селектора, прямо в `if`'е, чтобы получилось так: `if(inp...ase() && input.matches('.moy_textovy_input'))`, только замените селектор на тот, какой совпадает с инпутом у которого нужно ограничение. Предполагаю что у вас какие-то из этих селекторов: `.text > input:first-of-type` или `.text > input:not(input ~ input)`, но без конкретной разметки непонятно. Вам стоит [опубликовать новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), где также будет условие ограничивать именно какой из `<input>`'ов, а сейчас мой ответ полностью отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @JandosM а на данный момент, прошу отметить лучший ответ галочкой. (Чтобы отметить какой-то ответ галочкой, то-есть как правильный, нужно нажать галочку слева от ответа)

Comment: Вы правы, я изначально пропустил второй инпут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1489839/535055

Answer (score 1):

Можно ограничить без JS атрибутом `maxlength`.. Здесь представлены оба варианта.

```js
let inp = document.querySelectorAll('.text > input');//Выбираем все инпуты

inp.forEach(e=>{
  e.addEventListener('input', maxlength);//Вешаем слушатель на каждый
});

function maxlength(){//Один обработчик для всех инпутов
  this.value = this.value.substr(0,15);
}
```

```html
<div class='text'>  <input type="text" > </div>
<div class='text'>  <input type="text" > </div>
<div class='text'>  <input type="text" maxlength="15"> </div>
```