# Один обработчик на несколько инпутов, в нескольких дивах с двумя инпутами

Tags: javascript, html

Для уточнения [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489796/), здесь код с решением, которое нужно дополнить... есть несколько дивов (здесь привел только два, в каждом по два инпута). Нужно ограничить только инпуты `name="btn_name1"` и `name="btn_name2"` в каждом диве.

```
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Решение ниже касается всех инпутов... А нужно чтобы ограничивал только инпуты `name="btn_name1"` и `name="btn_name2"` в каждом диве.

```
<script>    

  window.addEventListener('input', e => {
    let input = e.target

    if(input.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
      input.value = input.value.slice(0, 15)
    }
  })    

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение 1

Как я и говорил вам, нужно использовать метод `matches`:

```js
window.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target

  if(input.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && input.matches('[name^="btn_name"]')) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, 15)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

## Решение 2

Можно также проверять саму строку атрибута, так к тому же будет более компилябельно со старыми браузерами.

```js
window.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target

  if(input.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && input.getAttribute('name').indexOf('btn_name') === 0) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, 15)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

## Решение 3

Можно вместо `getAttrbiute` использовать `name`, а вместо `indexOf(...) === 0` использовать `startsWith`, вот так:

```js
window.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target

  if(input.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && input.name.startsWith('btn_name')) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, 15)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name1" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="link2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="btn_name2" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
       <button type="submit" name="update_telegram" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

## Как это работает?

В первом решении я проверял атрибут на наличее строки `btn_name` в начале (Как и во втором), я это сделал с помощью возможности CSS на поиск элементов с каким атрибутом и с каким-то его значением (и не только, подробней можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)).

Во втором же решении, я использовал `getAttribute` который позволяет получить значение атрибута (в виде строки), а там уже используя `indexOf` я проверял, равняется ли текущий индекс нулю (То есть начинается ли строка на какую-то другую строку).

В третьем решении я сразу обратился к пропорции `name` (которая равняется атрибуту `name` в DOM дереве) и поверил, начинается ли строка на `btn_name`, уже используя метод `startsWith(...)` (который эквиволентен записи: `indexOf(...) === 0`).

Comment: Если мой ответ вам показался полезным и ответил на ваш вопрос, прошу отметить его галочкой.

Comment: Отлично! Всё работает. Выбрал 2-вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: @JandosM не за что! :)